# UITextField causing crash when tapped. Only happening on one device

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I had published my app to AppStore for some time now and all types of devices are using it . Latest version using it ios 8.4.1 on iPhone 6 as well as 6 plus.

I got a feedback from a user stating when he installed the app, came to the login page, 
there are two `UITextField`.

email--> `UITextField` -- `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress`

passswd---> `UITextField` secure type

If he taps on email textfield app crashes.
but if he taps on passwrd, its normal.

I have gone through all the possibilities.
This is the first view i get after `AppDelegate` is called and there isn't any object other then textfield I am allocating. Also I can't get past this screen without entering credentials.

Now I get his crash report

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x362cd208 bool objc::DenseMapBase<objc::DenseMap<DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> > >, DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> >, true>::LookupBucketFor<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> >(DisguisedPtr<objc_object> const&, std::__1::pair<DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long> const*&) const + 3
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x362cd3ad objc::DenseMapBase<objc::DenseMap<DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> > >, DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> >, true>::FindAndConstruct(DisguisedPtr<objc_object> const&) + 16
2   libobjc.A.dylib                0x362cd3ad objc::DenseMapBase<objc::DenseMap<DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> > >, DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> >, true>::FindAndConstruct(DisguisedPtr<objc_object> const&) + 16
3   libobjc.A.dylib                0x362cba2b objc_object::sidetable_retain() + 66
4   Foundation                     0x2874b755 +[__NSBundleTables bundleTables] + 40
5   Foundation                     0x285b49a9 +[NSBundle bundleForClass:] + 176
6   UIKit                          0x2afc03c9 -[UIWindow isInternalWindow] + 76
7   UIKit                          0x2b2540f5 +[UIWindow _enumerateWindowsIncludingInternalWindows:onlyVisibleWindows:withBlock:] + 120
8   UIKit                          0x2aff10d7 +[UIWindow allWindowsIncludingInternalWindows:onlyVisibleWindows:forScreen:] + 130
9   UIKit                          0x2aff104f +[UIWindow allWindowsIncludingInternalWindows:onlyVisibleWindows:] + 30
10  UIKit                          0x2b02ae4f -[UIViewController _window] + 238
11  UIKit                          0x2afbc7bd -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 104
12  UIKit                          0x2afbc71d -[UIViewController view] + 24
13  Sentieo                        0x003dd21f -[UIViewController(TLViewController) tlsw_viewDidLoad]
14  UIKit                          0x2afbc9af -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 602
15  UIKit                          0x2afbc71d -[UIViewController view] + 24
16  Sentieo                        0x003dd21f -[UIViewController(TLViewController) tlsw_viewDidLoad]
17  UIKit                          0x2afbc9af -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 602
18  UIKit                          0x2afbc71d -[UIViewController view] + 24
19  Sentieo                        0x003dd21f -[UIViewController(TLViewController) tlsw_viewDidLoad]
20  UIKit                          0x2afbc9af -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 602
21  UIKit                          0x2afbc71d -[UIViewController view] + 24
22  Sentieo                        0x003dd21f -[UIViewController(TLViewController) tlsw_viewDidLoad]
23  UIKit                          0x2afbc9af -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 602
24  UIKit                          0x2afbc71d -[UIViewController view] + 24
25  Sentieo                        0x003dd21f -[UIViewController(TLViewController) tlsw_viewDidLoad]
26  UIKit                          0x2afbc9af -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 602
27  UIKit                          0x2afbc71d -[UIViewController view] + 24
28  Sentieo                        0x003dd21f -[UIViewController(TLViewController) tlsw_viewDidLoad]
29  UIKit                          0x2afbc9af -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 602
30  UIKit                          0x2afbc71d -[UIViewController view] + 24
31  Sentieo                        0x003dd21f -[UIViewController(TLViewController) tlsw_viewDidLoad]
32  UIKit                          0x2afbc9af -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 602
33  UIKit                          0x2afbc71d -[UIViewController view] + 24
```

my textfields are:

```
self.loginView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f*widthRatio,200.0f*widthRatio, 280.0f*widthRatio,165.0f*widthRatio)];
self.loginView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:65/255.0 green:121/255.0 blue:173/255.0 alpha:1.0];
//25 47 70
// 5
self.loginView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:25/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:70/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
[self.loginView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
[self.loginView.layer setCornerRadius:5.0];
[self.view addSubview:self.loginView];
self.username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(19.0f*widthRatio,10.0f*widthRatio, 241.0f*widthRatio,40.0f*widthRatio)];
self.username.borderStyle =UITextBorderStyleNone;
self.username.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:35/255.0 green:75/255.0 blue:109/255.0 alpha:1.0];
self.username.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
self.username.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
self.username.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:25/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:70/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
self.username.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(15, 0, 0);
UIColor *color=[UIColor colorWithRed:155/255.0 green:193/255.0 blue:228/255.0 alpha:1.0];

self.username.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"E-mail" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];

self.username.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
self.username.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.username.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
self.username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
self.username.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
self.username.delegate = self;
[self.loginView addSubview:self.username];
self.password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(19.0f*widthRatio,55.0f*widthRatio, 241.0f*widthRatio,40.0f*widthRatio)];
self.password.borderStyle =UITextBorderStyleNone;
self.password.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:35/255.0 green:75/255.0 blue:109/255.0 alpha:1.0];
self.password.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
self.password.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:25/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:70/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
self.password.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(15, 0, 0);
self.password.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Password" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
self.password.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
self.password.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.password.secureTextEntry = YES;
self.password.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
self.password.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
self.password.delegate = self;
[self.loginView addSubview:self.password];
```

This `UIViewController` has `UITextFieldDelegate` set
with `textFieldShouldReturn:` implemented.

I have no idea how to remove the for him

Conclusion till now

1) as no body else could replicate the issue i guess, this guy needs to freshly install the app.

2) difference between password and email fields is secure=yes/no
   so if he might be using different keyboard.

3) is any notification is triggering.

Textfield delegate code

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

    if (theTextField == self.username) {
        DataObject *obj = [DataObject getInstance];
        obj.firstlogin = true;
        // whem return key pressed on username textfield, focus shifts to password textfield
        [self.password becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (theTextField == self.password) {
        [self.password resignFirstResponder];
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        self.apiConnection=nil;
        [self login:self];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `UITextFieldDelegate` code.

Comment: Comment `DataObject *obj = [DataObject getInstance]; obj.firstlogin = true;` And lets me know the result. Please!

Comment: sorry i was away. will keep you updated.
so this has no affect on the issue.

data object instance is like this

+(DataObject *)getInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(instance==nil)
        {
            instance= [DataObject new];
            instance.visitedToLeftPage = NO;
            instance.visitedToRightPage = NO;
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

where every property is synthesized.

Comment: another thing is why is it crashing only for one guy.
he is on iphone 6 ios8.4.1 version.
and mine is also not crashing.

Comment: It was crash in `libobjc.A.dylib`. And I don't know exactly what is it.

Comment: Is it expected to have so many `[UIViewController(TLViewController) tlsw_viewDidLoad]` in your trace?

Comment: I dont think so. From `AppDelegate` I go to `loginviewcontroller` as root viewcontroller.
In this view there is one imageview, and and couple of textfield and a subview. thats all.